# How to setup a basic python server to respond to POSTs

Tags: python, django, server

So I've written some code that I want to be able to run from a server. I understand how to use POST requests to send the data to the server and how to interpret the response, but I'm hitting a wall as far as setting up the server to listen for those requests and determine which code to run. I have a server with port 80 open and capable to listen. My code has been pushed to the server as well. I've tried looking into [some Django tutorials,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/) but they are a bit more complicated than I can seem to wrap my head around. I have never worked with servers before, but I do have an understanding of sockets and how to use urllib2. Can anyone help me figure out how to set this server up?

Comment: You should have a look into `flask`. It's a lot easier to start with than `django`.

Comment: Also prefer `requests` over `urllib2`. And `curl` (the shell command) is worth knowing the basics of.

Answer (score 3):

Django is great, but its a framework and takes a bit to learn.

The easiest and quickest to start with is a library like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html). Import it, define a route and a function to receive the request, and you are done.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

They has the server included, just start it from the shell and you can connect to it.

Of course, if you expect any larger amount of traffic, you will need to put this behind a proper web server, like Nginx.